# Wo kann man eine gute Quelle finden, die Substantive mit Präpositionen verbindet?

Tags: preposition, noun

Ich suche eine gute Quelle, die mir die entsprechende Präposition fur ein Substantiv geben würde.  Das könnte entweder estas Gedrucktes (ich habe schon einige Bücher von Duden) oder etwas online sein.  Aber umfassend soll es sein, d.h., nicht nur mit 20 oder 50 oder 100 Substantive, sondern mit der Mehrheit. Zum Beispiel, wenn ich das Substantiv "Vorstellung" (Einbildung) habe, ich möchte wissen, ob man die Präpositionen "auf", "von", "über" oder eine andere benutzen sollte?  (Ich schätze, dass die Antwort "von" ist, weil das Stilwörterbuch von Duden so ein Beispiel für "Vorstellung" hat, trotzdem weiss ich nicht, ob dieses Buch so eine Kombination für jedes jeweiliges Substantive hat.) Ich hätte an ein Wörterbuch gedacht, aber die scheinen nicht allzu hilfreich zu sein.

Ich weiss, dass es einige Webseiten gibt, die das Thema behandeln und eine Liste von einigen Kombinationen haben, aber, wie gesagt, ich suche etwas Umfassendes.

Außerdem, möchte ich wissen, ob es so eine Quelle auch für Verb-Präpositionen gibt.  Davon gibt es ziemlich umfassende Liste online, aber noch einmal, einem steht nur ein Teil des Wortschatzes zu Verfügung.

Comment: Eine Antwort müßte wahrscheinlich dafür argumentieren, daß es eine solche Quelle nicht geben kann. Daher verweise ich nur zum Zweck der Unterhaltung auf das folgende Buch, welches man für 540 EUR erwerben kann: https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110256093.

Comment: @DavidVogt Direkt gekauft!

Comment: @DavidVogt Erstaunlich, dass es so teuer ist!  Aber in Hinsicht darauf, dass es eine solche Quelle nicht geben kann, würde ich sagen, dass das, was ich suche, wirklich irgendwie in einem Wörterbucheintrag zu finden sein sollte, d.h., sucht man ein Wort (Substantiv), dann beinhaltet die Definition die normalen Präpositionen, mit denen das Wort benutzt wird.  Aber vielleicht wäre das nicht möglich...ich weiss es nicht.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eine richtige Quelle kenne ich nicht, aber ein kostenloser Ansatz wäre die [DWDS-Korpussuche](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpora/kern). Sie unterstützt auch die Suche nach Wortarten, z.B. gibt die Suche nach `Vorstellung $p=AP*` Textbelege, wo eine Apposition auf "Vorstellung" folgt. Abgesehen von einigen Stellen, wo die Präposition zu einem anderen Satzglied gehört, sieht man sehr deutlich, dass die Präposition "von" vorherrscht.

Schließt man dann "Vorstellung von" mit der Suche `Vorstellung $p=AP* && !Vorstellung von` explizit aus, sieht man auch, dass "Vorstellung" auch mit "über" kombiniert wird.

Was alles mit der Korpussuche möglich ist, ist unter https://www.dwds.de/d/korpussuche beschrieben.