# Wie lernt man die Kollokationen zwischen Präpositionen und anderen Wortarten am besten, auf höherem Niveau (C1/C2)?

Tags: preposition, verb, noun, learning, collocation

Mir hat mein Deutschlehrer ein Blatt gegeben, wo die fehlenden Präpositionen auszufüllen sind.  Es ist auf höherem Niveau (C2), und ich habe bemerkt, dass es manchmal wirklich schwierig ist, die Kollokationen zwischen Substantiven, bzw. Verben, und den korrekten Präpositionen zu finden.  Man hat mir vorgeschlagen, das alles in Wörterbüchern nachzuschlagen, aber im Duden, zum Beispiel, gibt es wirklich wenige solche Verbindungen.  Die [DWDS-Korpussuche](https://www.dwds.de/d/korpussuche), die [man mir früher empfohlen hat](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/75682/41028), hat mir geholfen, aber so geht es etwas langsam vorwärts, und oftmals kann ich nicht finden was ich will.  Gibt es, Eures Erachtens,  eine andere Methode oder eine Strategie, die Verhältnisse zwischen den Präpositionen und anderen Wortarten zu entdecken und zu lernen?  Ich habe schon ein Buch über die üblichsten Beispiele, aber ich meine auf höherem Niveau, d.h., ich möchte das alles ausführlich machen um meine Kenntnisse zu vervollständigen.  Ich schätze, dass viel nur durch Lesen zu bekommen ist -- aber wenn man es schneller und ein bisschen systematischer machen möchte?

Comment: Lernen schneller als durch das Lesen geht es mE nur mit schnellerem Lesen (im Sinne, mehr Stunden, mehr Quellen usw. pro Tag). Beachte, dass C2 ein Muttersprachlerniveau ist (schon fiktiv, denn wir werden es nicht sein, aber es ist die schwierigste DaF-Prüfung), d.h. es braucht nicht nur die Motivation und Energie, sondern unbedingt auch Zeit.